# Third-order recurrence with non-constant coefficients

Tags: recurrence-relations

During the study of a problem, I encountered this recurrence:
$$
a_n=a_{n-1}+2^{n-3}a_{n-2}+a_{n-3},\ n\geq 4
$$
with $a_1=0$, $a_2=1$ and $a_3=1$. Does anyone know a way to obtain an explicit expression for $a_n$?

I tried in several ways (order reduction, particular solutions), but without success. I also looked it up in OEIS and tried with some numerical simulations, again ended up empty-handed.

Comment: Are you sure that you have made no typo?

Comment: Yes, I checked again: that is the recurrence I have. Am I missing something?

Comment: I checked it and no solution was found.

Comment: What are you referring to? The sequence $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}$ is well-defined in the above way.

Comment: @AlessioDV I am afraid that there is no  easy "closed formula" . May I ask why you need an explicit formula? Are you interested in its asymptotics?

Comment: This is also my worry... My original problem is the following. Let $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}$ the sequence above and let $(b_n)_{n\geq 1}$ be the sequence satisfying the same recurrence but with initial conditions $b_1=0$, $b_2=0$ and $b_3=1$. The sequence $\left(\frac{a_n}{b_n}\right)_{n\geq 3}$ does not have limit and I also know that the sub-sequence with odd indices and the one with even indices converge to two different limits. My final aim is to find explicitly these two limits.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a_n=\int_{-\infty}^\infty2^{nt}K(t)~dt$ ,

Then $\int_{-\infty}^\infty2^{nt}K(t)~dt=\int_{-\infty}^\infty2^{(n-1)t}K(t)~dt+2^{n-3}\int_{-\infty}^\infty2^{(n-2)t}K(t)~dt+\int_{-\infty}^\infty2^{(n-3)t}K(t)~dt$

$\int_{-\infty}^\infty2^{nt}K(t)~dt-\int_{-\infty}^\infty2^{nt}2^{-t}K(t)~dt-\int_{-\infty}^\infty2^{n(t+1)}2^{-2t-3}K(t)~dt-\int_{-\infty}^\infty2^{nt}2^{-3t}K(t)~dt=0$

$\int_{-\infty}^\infty2^{nt}K(t)~dt-\int_{-\infty}^\infty2^{nt}2^{-t}K(t)~dt-\int_{-\infty}^\infty2^{nt}2^{-2t-1}K(t-1)~dt-\int_{-\infty}^\infty2^{nt}2^{-3t}K(t)~dt=0$

$\int_{-\infty}^\infty((1-2^{-t}-2^{-3t})K(t)-2^{-2t-1}K(t-1))2^{nt}~dt=0$

$\therefore(1-2^{-t}-2^{-3t})K(t)-2^{-2t-1}K(t-1)=0$

$(1-2^{-t}-2^{-3t})K(t)=2^{-2t-1}K(t-1)$

$K(t)=\dfrac{2^tK(t-1)}{2^{3t+1}-2^{2t+1}-2}$

$K(t)=\theta(t)\prod\limits_{k=0}^\infty\dfrac{2^{k+t}}{2^{3k+3t+1}-2^{2k+2t+1}-2}$ , where $\theta(t)$ is an arbitrary periodic functions with unit period

$\therefore a_n=\Theta(n)\int_{-\infty}^\infty\prod\limits_{k=0}^\infty\dfrac{2^{k+(n+1)t}}{2^{3k+3t+1}-2^{2k+2t+1}-2}~dt$ , where $\Theta(n)$ is an arbitrary periodic functions with unit period

But this is only one of the group of the linear independent solution. I have no idea to find another groups of the linear independent solution, since third order linear recurrence relations unlike third order linear differential equations which have reduction of order.

Answer (score 0):

**Numerical experiment**

Writing in *Wolfram Mathematica 12.0*:

```
nmax = 200;
recurrence = {f[n] == f[n - 1] + 2^(n - 3) f[n - 2] + f[n - 3]};
seqA = RecurrenceTable[{recurrence, f[1] == 0, f[2] == 1, f[3] == 1}, f, {n, 3, nmax}];
seqB = RecurrenceTable[{recurrence, f[1] == 0, f[2] == 0, f[3] == 1}, f, {n, 3, nmax}];

ListPlot[seqA/seqB]
N[seqA[[nmax - 3]]/seqB[[nmax - 3]], 20]
N[seqA[[nmax - 2]]/seqB[[nmax - 2]], 20]
```

I get:

> [image]
>
> 1.8058254356604270947
>
> 2.1654873668496381087

which is what is desired.